A sci-fi movie about alien shapeshifter
I'm looking for the name of a movie. Here is the description:

The alien came to the Earth by an egg-shaped spacecraft.
The alien is blue in colour and is a shapeshifter in a human shape.
The alien has turned his hand into an atm card and insert it into an atm machine.
The alien turns into a cat to escape from a fire.
The alien has some attachment to a human.

I watched it more than ten years ago. It is in English.
The whole alien was blue in colour, like it was made of water. It had no face.
I am not sure whether it was originally humanoid, but it definitely could be and actually had been in a human form. It did not wear clothes, but after it shapeshifted into human form, it also shapeshifted the clothes.
That's all I can remember. 

Was there more than one type of alien? I'm thinking that Critters had a fairly egg shaped ship (for the critters) and there was a bounty hunter alien - if memory serves. My memory could be off though, I saw the movie decades ago. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090887/

When you say the alien had no face, do you mean no eyes, no mouth - that kind of thing? Also, did it look computer generated or a person in make up?

After looking at the list of alien shape-shifting movies, Prey (1977) appears to be the one you might be looking for. It has the same plot in start as you have described.

At night, a carnivorous, shape-shifting alien named Kator lands in the woods of rural England. The vanguard of an invasion force, his mission is to evaluate the suitability of humans as a source of food for his species. Stumbling across Anderson and Sandy, a couple having a tryst in their parked car, he kills both and assumes the appearance of Anderson.




Though this matches most of the description, but confirm me this is the movie you're looking for.

is it the movie OP looking for?

This matches most of the description though.

Do I need OP confirmation to award the bounty? It's going to expire in 2-3 days.

@Vahn you are giving the bounty so final call should be in your hand. But for curtsy you can ask OP in comment, rest if you think answer deserve bounty, give it to him, rest don't.

ok. I'll wait until the last day to award the bounty.

You looking for The Tomorrow Man(1996)

egg-shaped spacecraft: 00:02:37
blueskin android shapeshifter: 00:06:50
turned his hand into an atm card: 00:40:52
turns into a cat: 00:22:29

